# Camera for live feed-transfer to external monitor in adjacent room?

Tags: live, camera

I need a camera that functions like a surveillance or webcamera but that I can output to a computer monitor (via adapters) with a VGA-cable. I could perhaps use a normal camcorder for this, but I find those to be too expensive for our simple needs.

Basically, I want the cheap price and simple functionality of a webcam but the possibility to connect it to a computer monitor using only adapters (not running through a computer).

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

A [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) might be what you are looking for.  It is a credit card sized Arm based computer running Raspbian (a Debian variant), and at $25 it may even be cheaper than buying several adapters.

You could simply attach a web cam to the Pi and attach the monitor or TV via HDMI or Component out.  To get to VGA you will need a [converter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003O55U8K) which you can get for about $30.

Comment: As far as a digital solution goes, I like this the best, since it allows me to use a webcam. Thanks for your creativity!

Answer (score 0):

A web cam is digital and designed to output a stream and be controlled over USB, it outputs a digital feed, you will need something to translate that to an analog feed that the VGA monitor can understand.  You really can't do it without a computer, but a simple cheap computer could do the job.  It doesn't require particularly sophisticated hardware, but a cheap camcorder with an analog output would probably do the job more cheaply and easily.

Comment: I know that, it's the very point of my question. But what I want is not a camcorder. A camcorder is used for recording and for collecting video. All I want is a simple stream/feed. What I'm asking is if there is a type of camera that does this simply? What I want is very basic, an analog webcam if you will. Is there such a thing?

Comment: Camcorders are not expensive and are your cheapest option.  They come as cheap as [$30](http://www.officedepot.com/a/products/323206/Vivitar-DVR426HD-Digital-Video-Recorder-With/?Channel=Google&mr:trackingCode=7DFBCCDE-54D6-E111-A306-001517384FBA&mr:referralID=NA&mr:adType=pla&mr:ad=22395426956&mr:keyword=&mr:match=&mr:filter=20224360076&cm_mmc=Mercent-_-Googlepla-_-Technology+Cameras_Camcorders-_-323206).

Comment: @burnso A camcorder can also send live video directly to a monitor.  The one mentioned by AJHenderson will do just that.  You may still need an adapter to get it to VGA if that is required, but it still is a really simple way to go.

Comment: @AJHenderson I realize that, but I feel camcorders such as the one you linked are not built to last. I need a camera that can be kept running for a few hours of time per instance. These are not great for that purpose.

Comment: @friend-of-george Thanks! But as I said above it is not optimal. I will probably try using a simple DV camera, just without tape. Sometimes older stuff is simply better for this kind of purpose. Nothing digital to mess things up.

Thanks for both of your answers! I hope I did not come across as rude, it is not my intent.

Comment: @burnso No problem.

Comment: @burnso - A DV camera is also digital (DV = digital video).  If battery life is an issue, is there a reason it can't be run off a power adapter?  You are going to need power for the monitor anyway.  Also, cheap web cams are not built to last either.  Either you get something cheap and it isn't built to last or you get something good that is.  You could also look at cameras that are specifically built for security systems as they are generally durable and cheap.